# how to avoid displaying rejected value if spring validation is failed at request bean validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

From below log we can see ***rejected value*** is display user data(example: User PII data with some special characters)

`[Field error in object 'Customer' on field 'FirstName': rejected value [robert% steve];`

So we tried to use **@ControllerAdvice**, **MethodArgumentNotValidException** and customize default error msg to show defined error msg.

But somehow this approach is not working for us with feature testcases. So do there any configuration not to display rejected value? or to show rejected value with masking?

thanks.

Comment: please someone help me with this issue

Comment: You don't need "an answer from a reputable source" for this question, seems overkill.

Comment: @MorBlau sorry i didnt get ur comment.

Comment: Please show: 2. How you tried 1. A sample/representative "feature test case" (not working) 3. Maybe some more log/stacktrace(/context), if you have (4. Tried debugging!?)

Comment: @developer you set a bounty with the flag "answer from a reputable source", but you just need an answer. You don't need the highest authority on spring validation to reply.

Comment: Need more details. Can you plz share skeleton code for ControllerAdvice that you used and the stacktrace you got in your log?

Comment: please show an example of your code with the points raised by @xerx593

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have found the right solution here. I was not sure that "rejected value" throws MethodArgumentNotValidException. Once I verified that, other things fall into the right place.

**Cause:**

Spring already has a base class **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** which handles **MethodArgumentNotValidException** specifically using **handleMethodArgumentNotValid()** method. So your method in @ControllerAdvice class is never called.

**Solution:**

**Override ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValid() method** & add your own custom logic there.

**Sample code:**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> error = Map.of("message", "Field value not valid.");
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, error, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set your own custom validation annotation, set your own validation rules and rejection message:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyValidator.class) 
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD }) // set the desired context
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyValidation {
    String message() default "Validation error! Not going to display rejected value.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

You can also set multiple validators in the `@Constraint`, and they will run consecutively.

The validator:

```
public class MyValidator implements 
  ConstraintValidator<MyValidation, String> { // here you set the validated field type, e.g. String

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyValidation value) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value,
        ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        ... // some validation logic
        return true/false;
    }

}
```

Then simply add your annotation to the validated field. You can even change the message at that point:

```
@MyValidation(message = "Error!")
String validField;
```

For more deep-dive info, you can check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: custome validator is to validate business level validation for variable level vaidation we are using spring validation framework like (firstname should be between 2 to 35 characters) etc. this wont help me

Comment: That's exactly the scenario where I used this custom validation - I set for example a @SecurePassword annotation and added it to the password field of a request model object. Then the signup controller would return a custom message like "Password should include x, y and z" (you get the gist).

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to see validation exceptions logged, but without the field values, you can add your own `HandlerExceptionResolver` that'll log your `MethodArgumentNotValidException` the way you need. Here's an example:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void extendHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> resolvers) {
        int beforeDefaultExceptionResolver = resolvers.size() - 1;
        resolvers.add(beforeDefaultExceptionResolver, new DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver() {

            @Override
            protected String buildLogMessage(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
                if (ex instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException validationEx) {
                    // example, modified from org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException#getMessage
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Validation failed for argument [")
                            .append(validationEx.getParameter().getParameterIndex()).append("] in ")
                            .append(validationEx.getParameter().getExecutable().toGenericString());
                    BindingResult bindingResult = validationEx.getBindingResult();
                    if (bindingResult.getErrorCount() > 1) {
                        sb.append(" with ").append(bindingResult.getErrorCount()).append(" errors");
                    }
                    sb.append(": ");
                    for (ObjectError error : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
                        sb.append('[');
                        if (error instanceof FieldError fieldError) {
                            sb.append("Field error in object '" + fieldError.getObjectName() + "' on field '" + fieldError.getField() + "'");
                        }
                        else {
                            sb.append(error);
                        }
                        sb.append("] ");
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
                }

                return super.buildLogMessage(ex, request);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you don't want to see validation exceptions logged at all, just set the following loggers' level to `ERROR` in your `application.yml`:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver: error
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver: error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `@InitBinder` for that, then validate your field before hand over :

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
   binder.addValidators(new FirstNameValidate());
}

public class FirstNameValidate implements Validator {

   @Override 
   public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
       // code implementation ...
   }

   @Override 
   public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
       // code implementation ...
   }
}
```