# @ControllerAdvice not catch MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, runtime-error

I want to catch errors from a global point with Controller Advice.

I created my ControllerAdvice class in this way, but I get an error when running the project.

```
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    List<ErrorEntity> localerrorEntitiesList = new ArrayList<>();

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> MethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException methodArgumentNotValidException){

        try {

            for (FieldError methodArgument : methodArgumentNotValidException.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
                localerrorEntitiesList.add(new ErrorEntity(methodArgument.getField(),methodArgument.toString()));
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse(localerrorEntitiesList),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        }catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse(localerrorEntitiesList), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }


    }


}
```

I have successfully caught many errors before, but I get an error when I want to catch MethodArgumentNotValidException.
Error output :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity mywebapp.demowebapp.exception.RestExceptionHandler.MethodArgumentNotValidException(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at mywebapp.demowebapp.DemoWebAppApplication.main(DemoWebAppApplication.java:17) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity mywebapp.demowebapp.exception.RestExceptionHandler.MethodArgumentNotValidException(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity mywebapp.demowebapp.exception.RestExceptionHandler.MethodArgumentNotValidException(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception}
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.addExceptionMapping(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:114) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.<init>(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:291) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:268) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1090) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1032) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 25 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74550143/14263933. I just wrote solution to a similar problem. Solution should be same.

Comment: Yes that's great and work! Thank you so much, I have a small question :) you know, MethodArgumentNotValidException returns us a message. When I get this message in bulk, it is very detailed and long. I can get the content of the message "There is already user with this email!" no problem here. 


However, I want to get the "path" information of it, I want to get PropertyPath by using "constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString()" but I could not find this property in MethodArgumentNotValidException. 

Thank you so much

Comment: MethodArgumentNotValidException doesn't have getPropertyPath() method. You can try this  List<FieldError> bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();  & see the options available there. By the way, plz upvote my original answer if you found it useful :)